# Jquery getting the values from sqlite database,cannot update the values

Tags: html, sqlite, jquery-mobile

I have done a program to insert and update records in the sqlite database and to view the data in the database in Websql.

I have created text box field and when we enter the data it gets stored in the database by clicking the submit button.

I could not achieve in updating the records in the database with new values entered in the textbox.

However I can insert the data in the database,and cannot update the values in the database.

**Here is my coding.**

```
var updateStatement = "UPDATE login SET username=?,password=?,firstname = ?, lastname = ? ,hobby=?,email=? WHERE id=?";
var db=window.openDatabase('MYFORM','1.0','MYFORM',200000);

$(document).ready(function()
{
initDatabase();
$("#update").click(updateRecord);
});


function initDatabase()  // Function Call When Page is ready.

{

try {

    if (!window.openDatabase)  // Check browser is supported SQLite or not.

    {

        alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.');

    }

    else {

showRecords();

    }

}

catch (e) {

    if (e == 2) {

        // Version number mismatch. 

        console.log("Invalid database version.");

    } else {

        console.log("Unknown error " + e + ".");

    }

    return;

    }

    }
function updateRecord() // Get id of record . Function Call when Delete Button Click..

{
    var usernamenew = $('input:text[id=username]').val().toString();

    var passwordnew = $('input:password[id=pass]').val().toString();

    var firstnamenew = $('input:text[id=firstname]').val().toString();

    var lastnamenew = $('input:text[id=lastname]').val().toString();

    var hobbynew = $('input:text[id=hobby]').val().toString();

    var emailnew= $('input:text[id=email]').val().toString();

    var useridnew = $("#id").val();

    db.transaction(function (tx) { tx.executeSql(updateStatement,  [usernamenew,passwordnew,firstnamenew, lastnamenew,hobbynew,emailnew,Number(useridnew)],loadAndReset, onError) });

    }
```

**HTML**

```
<label for="username"> Username   :</label>
```

```
<label for="pass"> Password :</label>
<input name="password" type="password" id="pass" placeholder="your password" size="20"  maxlength="20"  width="20" />
<label for="firstname"> Firstname   :</label>
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"  placeholder="your full name"/>
<label for="lastname"> Lastname  :</label>
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"  placeholder="your last name"/>
<label for="hobby"> Hobby                :    </label>
<input type="text" name="hobby" id="hobby" placeholder="your hobby" /><br ><br >
<label for="email"> Email :</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email"  placeholder="Your email address"/><br > 
   <br >
<a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-btn-b "id="update" type="submit" >Update</a>
```

**UPDATED QUESTION**

I also have a function named showRecords() and once we call that function it will display all the records in the form of list and I have an edit button in the list and if I click that edit button it should load the particular records in the next page in a edit box ..ie..

If we click **id=1** it should load the records using loadRecords() function of **id=1** in the next page in an editbox and similarly to the other respective id's.

may I know how to achieve this plz help..

Coding for the showRecords function

```
function showRecords() // Function For Retrive data from Database Display records as list

{

$("#results").html('')

db.transaction(function (tx) {

    tx.executeSql(selectAllStatement, [], function (tx, result) {

        dataset = result.rows;

        for (var i = 0, item = null; i < dataset.length; i++) {

            item = dataset.item(i);

              var linkeditdelete = '<ul><li>' +  item['username'] + ' , ' + item['password'] + ' ,'  +item['firstname']+' , ' + item['lastname'] +' , ' + item['hobby']+','+item['email']+ '<a href="page4.html" onclick="loadRecord(' + 'id' + ') id="edit";">edit</a>' +' '  + '<a href="#" onclick="deleteRecord(' + item['id'] + ');">delete</a></li></ul>';

            $("#results").append(linkeditdelete);

        }

    });

});

}

function loadRecord(i)
{

var item = dataset.item(i);

$("#username").val((item['username']).toString());

$("#pass").val((item['password']).toString());

$("#firstname").val((item['firstname']).toString());

$("#lastname").val((item['lastname']).toString());

$("#hobby").val((item['hobby'])).toString();

$("#email").val((item['email']).toString());

$("#id").val((item['id']).toString());

}
```

Comment: try like this `var updateStatement = "UPDATE login SET username="+username+",password="+password+",firstname ="+firstname+", lastname = "+lastname+" ,hobby="+hobby+",email="+email+" WHERE id="+id;`

Comment: and your sqlexecute like `tx.executeSql("upadatequery,[],onsuccess);`

Comment: Tried but still not fixed!

Comment: Is this syntax correct?
  //db.transaction(function (tx) { tx.executeSql("UPDATE login SET (username= '"+usernamenew+"' ,password='"+passwordnew+"',firstname='"+firstnamenew+"' ,lastname='"+lastnamenew+"' ,hobby='"+hobbynew+"',email='"+emailnew+"') WHERE (id= '"+useridnew+"')");

   @Aravin

Comment: yes it is correct i used in my table.

Comment: i think you submit the page when update..so the problem occur here...the page submitted without update the database(because database take some time to insert values but the submit action does not wait for db actions)

Comment: after update what you are doing?

Comment: just getting the value from the database and display in textbox and if you want to update the data,you can update the values using the textbox and it gets updated in the database

Comment: Instead of `type="submit"` in update try with button

Comment: This was my code..
<a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-btn-b " id="btnUpdate" onclick="updateRecord()">Update</a>

should I use <button> command instead?

Comment: yes do the same..`<a  class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-btn-b " id="btnUpdate" onclick="updateRecord()">Update</a>`

Comment: and one more thing use `var usernamenew = $('#username').val()` no need for tostring and types...

Comment: have done as you said and no luck :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60952/discussion-between-sam-rogers-and-aravin).

Comment: are you using cordova/phonegap ?

Comment: Im using Cordova and for this Im first running it in the browser..

Comment: @Aravin I hv another query to ask,I shall update it in my question

Comment: yes ask ..if  i know i will ..

Comment: Please find my updated question above.

Comment: append the id in list(that is <li>) when click list need to pass the id to next page.After that using that id retrieve the particular id details for edit..

Comment: check this one http://www.raymondcamden.com/2011/10/20/Example-of-PhoneGaps-Database-Support

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you missed something in the creation of the table or when you identified the correct id (where the transaction has to replace the values).

I inserted your version on JSFiddle and putted also the query for the creation and insertion and it 
works.
   Have a look at this
http://jsfiddle.net/jm6bubp9/

And first run these

```
 db.transaction(function (tx) {
   tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS login (id , username, password, firstname, lastname, hobby, email )');
   });
db.transaction(function (tx) {
 tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO login values (55,2,3,4,5,6,7)") });

     }
```

Comment: I would like to getting the value from textbox and not passing values and updating,deleting the deleting the records stored

Comment: Hope this gets fixed soon!

Comment: I didn't get your problem.
It gets values from textbox!
In the example I filled first a random entry in the database.
You need to:
Insert the value (you said you managed well this step)
then copy the code that's on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jm6bubp9/3/
In this I don't know where did you get the value of ID field. For this reason early I inserted 55 a random value.

Comment: Id is a primary key which is set to auto increment...I could able to insert the values into the database,the only problem is updating the values..